# How to popup a messagebox on button click without using javascript

Tags: asp.net

I want to popup a message box without using javascript. I want to use c#.

I want to get the popup on the click event of submit button.

Comment: If i may ask - why would you not use javascript for a client-side task? Any you could mimic an messagebox with two views of the opened site, but thats not good to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

C# is used for server side scripts. Popups show on the client side, so client scripting is required. If you insist on calling this client script from code behind you could always use the [RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx) function.

```
public void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
        GetType(), 
        "popup", 
        "alert('hello world');", 
        true
    );
}
```

There are other alternatives of showing popups instead of using the old school `alert`: for example you could use the [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/) plugin based on the popular [jQuery framework](http://jquery.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a popup without using Javascript.  Javascript runs on the client side. Any code you write using C# in the code behind file runs on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use code that's executed on the client side to do this. This is normally done via JavaScript. The only other solution is to use Flash or Silverlight and code your application in those.

[This page](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Message-Box.aspx) presents one solution, however, it still uses JavaScript, but it's created the page load code rather than being specified in the aspx file so you are still using JavaScript. I know this is VB.NET code, but you should be able to translate it to C# quite easily.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
                                                           Handles Me.Load
    Dim myscript As String = "alert(document.getElementById('TextBox1').value);"
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "myscript", myscript,
                                                                            True)
End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
                                                            Handles Button1.Click
    Dim strMessage As String
    strMessage = "Hi, You clicked ClickMe button"
    'finishes server processing, returns to client.
    Dim strScript As String = "<script language=JavaScript>"
    strScript += "alert(""" & strMessage & """);"
    strScript += "</script>"

    If (Not ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("clientScript")) Then
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "clientScript",
                                                                     strScript)
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

c# is server sided, javascript is client sided (usually). if you want the client to receive a message without using javascript, you have to put it somewhere inside your html.

Answer (score -2):

VB.NET

Simply use "msgbox" with a message.

like:
msgbox("hello world!")

It will popup on your screen